# trouble with an if statement method in java

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

trying to work out how to finish off this method

With this version, the final "tax cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
public double calculateTax() {

  if (salary < 9440){
    double tax = 0;
  }
  else {
    double newSalary = salary - 9440;


    if (newSalary <= 32010) {
      double tax = newSalary*0.2;
    } else {
      double tax1 = 32010*0.2;
      double tax2 = (newSalary - 32010)*0.4;
      double tax = tax1 + tax2;
    }
  } 
  return tax;
}
```

However, with this version the "method does not return a result of type double"

```
public double calculateTax() {

  if (salary < 9440){
    double tax = 0;
  } else {
    double newSalary = salary - 9440;


    if (newSalary <= 32010) {
      double tax = newSalary*0.2;
    } else {
      double tax1 = 32010*0.2;
      double tax2 = (newSalary - 32010)*0.4;
      double tax = tax1 + tax2;

      return tax;
    }
  } 
}
```

I can't define a separate field for tax for this project - where should I be putting return tax? Thank you :)

Comment: You should look up `variable scope`.

Comment: Please check your curly brackets and re-indent your code accordingly.

Comment: Always carefully match your curly brackets!

Answer (score 7):

In the first case, the `tax` is within the `if` and `else` blocks, hence its not visible outside them. Thus the error at the return statement.

In the second case, the `return` is inside an `else` and that makes it a conditional return. Thus the second error.

All this boils down to a concept called `scope`. The scope of a variable is within the block it is defined. It cannot be accessed outside its declaration scope. The scope can be method level, block level, instance level, etc.

Declare the `tax` variable at the start of the method, outside any of the blocks and it'll work.

```
public double calculateTax() {
    double tax; // Declare here
    ..
    // Now remove double keyword from every other place where you've used tax
    // Use the tax created at the beginning of the method all around.
}
```

And finally, your `return` should be as in the first case. Outside any of the `if` or `else` blocks, because your method needs to `return` a double value under all circumstances(not conditionally).

Comment: @Nelly - Do [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it helped you!:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it at the start of your method.

```
double tax = 0;
```

then refer to it (without redefining it) elsewhere.   For example

```
tax = newSalary*0.2;
```

instead of

```
double tax = newSalary*0.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this, instead of declaring `tax` multiple times, which is not necessary.

```
public double calculateTax() {
    double tax = 0;

    //Other codes here (if else etc)

    return tax;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare tax outside of the if:

```
double tax;
if (salary < 9440){
   tax = 0;
}
else {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the `tax` variable at the beginning of the method (i.e., not inside any `if` block), and return it at the end:

```
public double calculateTax() {
    double tax = 0;
    double newSalary = salary;

    if (newSalary >= 9440) {
      double newSalary -= 9440;
    }

    if (newSalary <= 32010) {
      double tax = newSalary*0.2;
    }
    else {
      double tax1 = 32010*0.2;
      double tax2 = (newSalary - 32010)*0.4;
      tax = tax1 + tax2;
    }

    return tax;
}
```

Note: I tried to retain your variable names and flow wherever possible to make the answer easier to understand. You should, however, probably be using `double` literals instead of `int` literals (e.g., `32010.0` instead of `32010`) - or better yet, `double` constants.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing, badly formatted, and littered with magic numbers.  Style matters: pay more attention to how you write your code.  Sloppy style makes your code harder to read and understand.

I might write it this way:

```
public double calculateTax() {
    double tax = 0.0;
    if (salary < 9440) {
       tax = 0.0;
    } else {
       double newSalary = salary - 9440;
       if (newSalary <= 32010) {
           tax = newSalary*0.2;
       } else {
           double tax1 = 32010*0.2;
           double tax2 = (newSalary - 32010)*0.4;
           tax = tax1 + tax2;
       }
    } 
    return tax;
}
```

Or I might not.  Bad stuff.